# Nuxt app cannot access one REST API, but all others work

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I have a web app with a Django backend and a NuxtJS front end running in docker. The backend uses [REST framework JWT Auth](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) to control access. My URLs file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api/auth/login/', obtain_jwt_token),
path('api/auth/verify/', verify_jwt_token),
# other urls here
]
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    env_file:
     - deploy.env

    volumes:
      - .:/backend
    expose:
      - "8000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ng01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - backend

  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    links:
      - backend
```

These two methods work perfectly from postman when the docker container is running - I'm able to obtain and verify JWT tokens as expected.  However, when the front end calls these methods **the login method still works perfectly, but the verify method fails**. There are a number of other methods in my app that also work fine when called from the front end. Here is the error i get:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I find this really weird, as normally this message would imply some sort of CORS issue, but as the other methods work, I don't see how it can be the case here.

Here's how I'm calling the login/verify APIs from my front end (in my store.js file). Whenever the user refreshes the page, `nuxtServerInit` retrieves the token from the browser cookie and attempts to call the verify method to get the user profile in the front end

```
export const actions = {
  async refreshAuth ({ dispatch, commit }, token) {
    try {
      var { data } = await axios.post(endpoint + '/auth/verify/', { token })
      console.log(data)
      if (data.token) {
        commit('setUser', { token: data.token, profile: data.profile })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('refreshAuth failed due to an error')
      console.log(err)
    }
  },
  async nuxtServerInit ({ dispatch, commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.headers.cookie) {
      let { token } = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie)
      await dispatch('refreshAuth', token)
    }
  },
async login ({ commit }, { email, password }) {
    try {
      var { data } = await axios.post(endpoint + '/auth/login/', { email, password })
      await commit('setUser', {
        token: data.token,
        profile: data.profile
      })
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 401) {
        commit('setError', 'Invalid credentials')
      }
      if (err.response.status === 403) {
        commit('setUnverified', true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose file, please? Maybe you're missing a `network_mode: "host"` in the compose file, because you need that to access from inside container to the host using the same localhost interface.

Comment: Have added it above now

Comment: Try adding `network_mode: "host"` to `backend` service

Comment: that breaks nginx: ``ng01       | 2018/05/24 12:32:52 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "backend:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:3
ng01       | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:3
ng01 exited with code 1.``

Comment: here's my nginx config: ``upstream backend {
  ip_hash;
  server backend:8000;
}

# portal
server {
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;
}
``

Comment: ok, i managed to get nginx going again. But the issue still occurs

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a CORS issue. The `login` action was being called from a nuxt page, whereas the `refreshAuth` call was being made from `nuxtServerInit`. Bizarrely, `django-cors-headers` rejects the call when made by `nuxtServerInit`. The solution was to move the call to `refreshAuth` to the `created()` method of the default layout in nuxt